# How to trigger some javascript before CSS transition?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an element whose width increases when another element beside it is hovered over, i.e.

```css
.div2 {
  width: 0px;
  display: none;
  transition: width 2s;
}

.div1:hover ~ .div2 {
  width: 100px;
}
```

I want to change the display to block on mouseover, but before the CSS transition. Then, similarly, I want to change the display back to none after the CSS transition finishes. I tried using `.onmouseover` to set the display to block, but it set it after the CSS transition.

Is there any way to set the display to block before the CSS transition?

Comment: css and javascript don't communicate with each other. You can however, add you css classes to your html via javascript so that things happen in the order you want.

Comment: Can you post the whole code of what you have tried which you mention in question  as  .... "I tried using .onmouseover to set the display to block, but it set it after the CSS transition."

Comment: Surely you’re looking for :hover {display:block;}?

Comment: @mwilson How would you add the classes in order? I tried doing (I'm using jQuery here because it's easier)
`$(".div2").on("mouseover", function() {
  $(".div1").addClass("div1--block");
  $(".div1").addClass("div1--100w");
});` Do I need to add a small delay after adding one class?

Comment: @BenjaminJamesKippax No, because if I use `:hover { display: block; }`, the transition for the width doesn't really work (I forgot to include transition in post, I'll edit it in)

Comment: @Cosmos Yea, you can add delays so it matches your css timing.

Comment: @Cosmos fair. Always nice to try and find the simplest answer. Could you perhaps try using key frames and animations with a delay?

Comment: @mwilson Since I want the width transition to happen immediately after `display: block`, should I set the delay to 0? I tried `$(".div1").addClass("div1--block").delay(0).queue(function() {
      $(this).addClass("div1--100w").dequeue();
    });`. I'm not sure if that's a good way to do it, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your question, You can have two classes one for hidden (display :none) and another for visuallyHidden (may be visibility : hidden). On hover use visualy hidden class to get the css transition in effect(take help of JavaScript to add this class). You must take a help of setTimeout here (10 Ms ) should be fine to add another class which actually implements css transition. when it is un hovered you need to recycle logic again.  hope it helps